# How can I extract the following information through jsoup.parse

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, jsoup

I am doing some tests in kotlin, but I need to extract the following information, I am doing it in the following way but it is without success

I need extract the link from the following line

```
<li role="presentation" data-video="//misite.com/play?id=MTI4MzM3" class="tab-video">
```

I do it in the following way but I did not succeed returns me in white

```
Jsoup.parse(get(data).text).selectFirst("li.tab-video")?.attr("data-video") ?: return false
```

Comment: The query seems in order - it *should* return: `//misite.com/play?id=MTI4MzM3`. How does `get(data).text` look like?

Comment: If I need to get that value